# Asynchronous ajax call causing issue in KnockOutjs

Tags: asynchronous, knockout.js

I have a button on click of that i am calling something like :

**ViewModel:**

```
self.MyArray = ko.observableArray();

self.remove = function(c) {

    ko.utils.arrayForEach(c.sData(), function(ser) {
        if (ser.Check() == true) {
            self.MyArray.push(service);
            count++;
        }
    });

    if (count) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/LoadCustomer/?reason=" + reason,
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: ko.toJSON(self.MyArray),
            success: function(data) {
                ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.MyArray(), function(removedata) {
                    c.sData.remove(removedata);
                });
            }
        });
        self.MyArray([]);
    }

};
```

If i include `async:false` in my ajax call i get everything fine but if i didn't include `async` (its default property is true) i dont know somehow in my success function of ajax call `self.MyArray()` remains `Empty` but its not the case if i keep it false (Awkward).

Sometimes i fear like if i have series of ajax calls with `async:true` while loading into a observable array(OnLoad) there may be a slight chance of misplacement of data .

Help me understand .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason your observable array `MyArray` is empty sometimes is because this line of code `self.MyArray([]);` executing before the ajax call is done.  How about this instead -

```
if (count) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/LoadCustomer/?reason=" + reason,
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: ko.toJSON(self.MyArray),
        success: function (data) {
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.MyArray(), function (removedata) {
                c.sData.remove(removedata);
            });
        },
        complete: function() { // complete fires after success and error callbacks
            self.MyArray([]); // empty the array no matter what happens (error or success)
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: can i assume `complete` is some kind of `final` keyword at any cost  it will execute just in-case if there is a error

Comment: @supercool Yeah the `complete` callback will execute regardless of `error` or `success`.  [See #6 on callback hooks here about 3/4 into the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).  And it does fire before the `success` or `error` callback.  As long as you don't do anything asynchronous in it you will be ok.

Comment: @supercool In the previous comment I mean to say that the `complete` callback fires AFTER the `success` or `error` callback.  I think you know I meant this though :~)